# Intellisense not working for selenium in vs code with python

Tags: python, selenium, intellisense

While writing tests in vscode with python, intellisense is not working for selenium methods.

I have installed selenium by pip.
I have these extensions installed:
- Magic Python
- Python
- Python Extension Pack
- Python Test Explorer
- Test Explorer UI

In settings.json i have this line: 
"python.jediEnabled": false

```
import unittest
import json
from selenium import webdriver

class BaseClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        cls.driver.get(cls.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Jedi did the job. Closing.